# Spring Batch customize ItemReader for reading complex XML file sample

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch

I'm using Spring batch to read from a XML file and insert records to a database.
As my Investigations StaxEventItemReader is just for simple flat XML files and I should customize ItemReader to read the AcceptedRecord and FailedRecord Tags.
My XML file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Response>
    <Accept>
        <count>38210</count>
        <sumAmount>40371098000</sumAmount>
        <AcceptedRecords>
            <AcceptedRecord>0009950797043112379449051230000024570246916464000</AcceptedRecord>
            <AcceptedRecord>0009950797043194513728041270000021770212916719000</AcceptedRecord>
            <AcceptedRecord>0009950797043191439234041290000343670279916734000</AcceptedRecord>
        </AcceptedRecords>
    </Accept>
    <Reject>
        <count>1</count>
        <sumAmount>232000</sumAmount>
        <FailedRecords>
            <FailedRecord>0009951497043100005628276330000023208006001837009</FailedRecord>
        </FailedRecords>
    </Reject>
</Response>
```

Does everybody have an example? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "flat XML files"? In your example, please add more tags to see the pattern of your file and specify which target domain type your item reader is expected to read. We will then be able to help you customize your reader.

Comment: In current file Image if for example Accept tag has no child and be repeated. This is a flat XML file.

Comment: For example Responde root tag just have 100 Accept tag child. and Tags are non-hierarchical

Comment: And As I mentioned I need to read the AcceptedRecord and FailedRecord Tags.

Comment: The item reader reads items of one type. It could be either `AcceptedRecord`  or `FailedRecord`. So in your case, you would need two readers, one for each type. The `fragmentRootElementName` can be anywhere in your xml file, so in your example, you can specify the `fragmentRootElementName` as `AcceptedRecord` and the `StaxEventItemReader` will read the 3 tags.

Comment: You mean I should declare a Job with two steps and each step has One Item-reader. The first for AcceptedRecord  and the Second for FailedRecord?

Comment: yes, for example, because you can't read both types at the same time.

Comment: Tricky way clever man! Thanks a lot. I'll respond it back .